# How to add a column that contains the id value of the first distinct record for a set of duplicate records

Tags: sql, database, sybase

I have the following table named emp

| id | fname | lname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mihir | Sheth |
| 2 | Mit | Dasondi |
| 3 | Narra | Harsha |
| 4 | Mihir | Sheth |
| 5 | Shrey | Malvi |
| 6 | Mit | Dasondi |
| 7 | Ujas | Patel |

I want to alter the table emp and create a new column NewId, such that for duplicate records it will have the value of the id of the first occurence of distinct record.

For distinct records the value will be null in the NewId column. By the "first occurence of the distinct record" I mean the record that occurs first when sorted on basis of id column.

For a better understanding, please see the following.

| id | NewId | fname | lname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | Mihir | Sheth |
| 2 | null | Mit | Dasondi |
| 3 | null | Narra | Harsha |
| 4 | 1 | Mihir | Sheth |
| 5 | null | Shrey | Malvi |
| 6 | 2 | Mit | Dasondi |
| 7 | null | Ujas | Patel |

Please advise me on how to proceed and also keep in mind that I want the new column to be in the actual table, not in cte or other temporary table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first to add a column to the `emp` schema:

```
ALTER TABLE emp ADD NewId INT;
```

Then you can use a selection of the smallest ids for each employee and update the `emp` table where the id does not correspond to the minimum id:

```
UPDATE     emp 
INNER JOIN (SELECT fname, lname, MIN(id) AS id
            FROM emp
            GROUP BY fname, lname) min_emps
        ON emp.fname = min_emps.fname
       AND emp.lname = min_emps.lname
       AND emp.id   <> min_emps.id
SET emp.NewId = min_emps.id;
```

Here's a MySQL [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ti2by7yGgs1rPvorviuSM/0), though this may work in sybase too.

---

**Edit**: Given [Sybase documentation](https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1510/html/iqrefso/Update.htm) on update statements, the corresponding `UPDATE` statement for your problem may be the following:

```
UPDATE emp 
SET emp.NewId = min_emps.id;
FROM emp 
JOIN (SELECT fname, lname, MIN(id) AS id  
      FROM emp
      GROUP BY fname, lname             ) min_emps
  ON emp.fname = min_emps.fname
 AND emp.lname = min_emps.lname
 AND emp.id   <> min_emps.id
```

Comment: Update join syntax is highly database specific.  You should make sure that a MySQL update join would also work on Sybase.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 100% agree Tim. In fact in the last line of my answer I've specificly noted that this solution *may work in sybase too*. I'll leave that to the author of the question.

Comment: I have tried running both the update statements on my table. And both worked fine. Thank you very much for the help:)

Answer (score 3):

We can try using `MIN` as an analytic function here:

```sql
SELECT id, CASE WHEN id <> MIN(id) OVER (PARTITION BY fname, lname)
                THEN MIN(id) OVER (PARTITION BY fname, lname) END AS NewId,
       fname, lname
FROM emp
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This works fine. But what I want is to alter the table and add a new column for NewId and store this values in that column rather than retrieving them explicitly in select statement. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you want a computed column or do you want to do an update?  BTW I am not a Sybase expert; the above answer might be as far as I can take you.

Comment: Yep I understand. Thanks. Btw @lemon 's answer clears all my doubts.